# Find complex number z

Tags: complex-numbers

I am stuck with this question
 Find complex number $z$ for which $|z-1-i|=1$   and $\text{re}(z)=\text{im}(z)$

So  $z=a+ib$ , and re=im ,  $z=a+ai= a(1+i)$ 
What should I do next?
Thanks

Comment: Then represent the modulus $|z-1-i|$ in terms of $a$.

Comment: You can also use `\Re` $\Re$ and `\Im` $\Im$ for the real and imaginary parts, just in case you're new to MathJax. Welcome to the site, by the way!

Answer (score 2):

Then represent the modulus $|z-1-i|$ in terms of $a$:

$$|z-1-i| = |a-1+(a-1)i| = \sqrt{(a-1)^2 + (a-1)^2} = \sqrt{2(a-1)^2} = \sqrt2|a-1|$$

Equating that with $1$,

$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{2}|a-1| &= 1\\
|a-1| &= \frac1{\sqrt2}\\
a-1 &= \pm\frac1{\sqrt2}\\
a &= 1 \pm\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

$$|z-1-i|=|a+ai-1-i|=|(a-1)+(a-1)i|=\sqrt{2(a-1)^2}=1\iff a=1\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $$z-1-i=\cos t+i\sin t$$

$$\iff z=1+\cos t+i(1+\sin t)$$

So, we need $\cos t=\sin t\iff\tan t=1\iff t\equiv\dfrac\pi4\pmod{\pi}$